# Android email intent with formatted html in different mail providers

Tags: android, html, email, android-intent

I'm trying to start email intents and  using "put extra" to input some formatted html. So far i've come up with two defferent versions of starting the intents which handles the html correctly.

Nr1 (works with the standard mailprovider and the italics and bold is rendering correctly)

```
    String c = "<body> <i>sadkmasldkm</i> asdksmmsm <b> ssss </b></body>";  


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, content);
```

NR2 (Works with GMail correctly)

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my subject");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(c));
```

Notice the difference in the Html.fromHtml(c).

If i user Nr1 Gmail will not recognize it as Html, if i use Nr2 the standard mailprovider will recognize it as html but not format the  and  tags (it will just ignore them and show it as ordinary text). There is no difference if I set the type to "text/html" either.

I'm quite stuck here. Is there no way which works on both providers or is there any way of detecting which one the user have picked?